# Search function in plain HTML (No database)

Tags: html

This is likely the most ridiculous question I've ever had to ask but it's been a LONG time since I've ever worked with a static HTML site and I might not have had enough coffee this morning.

Can you have a search function on a static HTML site that does NOT have a database?

My client is migrating a site from ASP to HTML and they want to keep the search function on there but it literally is just a collection of static files. Nothing else. No Database, nothing.

Is this possible?

Do I need more coffee?

Comment: Check out solr, elastisearch, and lucene.

Comment: This apparently asks for information on services that index your site for you and maintain a database hosted elsewhere. There are several such services, ranging from simple customized Google search boxes to sophisticated and tailored solutions. But recommendations on software are considered off-topic at SO.

Answer (score 2):

Well it's not possible using only HTML. However it's possible to create a search function without a traditional database. But still - the data needs to come from somewhere, if not a database then perhaps a txt or xml file. That said, it can be achieved using HTML+JavaScript if you don't want to involve a server-side language.

There are many tutorials on how to create these types of search functions using for example XML as a data source. Just google something like "XML HTML Search" and you'll probably find what you're looking for :)